# Does it make sense to implement dotnet core webapi as async behind an AWS Lambda function?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm implementing a Rest Api using AWS API Gateway,AWS Lambda function and Dotnet core webapi.

I'm questioning if makes sense to implement the dotnet webapi service/controller as async? Are there any advantages?

Since for the AWS API Gateway / Lambda will redirect each requests to an available or new lambda function instance, and will not make parallel requests do the same instance and so dotnet web api component will not be called with multiple requests in parallel.

Thanks